# CKEditor: make font size combo-box editable or use a new control instead

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Any ideas how to make the CKEditor font size combo-box editable to allow a custom font size?

Or how can I add my own font size control instead of the combo-box?

For example, I want to replace the combo-box with an input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way for the user to enter a custom font size, but you can use `fontSize_sizes` configuration property to alter the default font sizes that are presented to the user.

From [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-fontSize_sizes):

> The list of fonts size to be displayed in the Font Size combo in the
>   toolbar. Entries are separated by semi-colons (';').
>
> Any kind of "CSS like" size can be used, like '12px', '2.3em', '130%',
>   'larger' or 'x-small'.
>
> A display name may be optionally defined by prefixing the entries with
>   the name and the slash character. For example, 'Bigger Font/14px' will
>   be displayed as 'Bigger Font' in the list, but will be outputted as
>   '14px'.
>
> config.fontSize_sizes = '16/16px;24/24px;48/48px;';
>
> config.fontSize_sizes = '12px;2.3em;130%;larger;x-small';
>
> config.fontSize_sizes = '12 Pixels/12px;Big/2.3em;30 Percent
>   More/130%;Bigger/larger;Very Small/x-small';

Comment: thanks but this doesn't help me; I need to give user a way to set a custom font size. Is there a way to replace the combo-box with my own control? For example, let's say I want to replace it with an input

Comment: Do you need this for convenience of the user, to type the value instead of selecting it? To be quicker?

Comment: user might want a specific value. it's impossible to harcode all possible values

Comment: From what I understand, you can't have an input field in the toolbar. I can think of 2 options: You can make a plugin that opens a dialog to type the font size (which would require one more click for the user) or you can have an input field outside ckeditor just above the toolbar, so you can use it to type the font size and hit Enter. I can easily show you the 2nd option if you're interested.

Comment: I *think* that I can help you with the 1st option too (plugin).